# How to show arrows symmetrically for self-loops in a dot graph

Tags: dot

I am working with a DFA which I have described in the dot file format. One of the nodes in my DFA has two self-loops, which I originally described with the following way

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  a -> a [color=blue]
  a -> a [color=green]
}
```

Which produces this output when I run `dot graph.gv -Tpng`

[image: Arrows on same side]

For symmetry reasons, I'd like to have the blue and the green arrows on opposite sides of the node. I can modify the `headport` and `tailport` of the green arrow to force it to start from the bottom of the node as follows:

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  a -> a [color=blue]
  a:sw -> a:se [color=green]
}
```

Unfortunately, that produces an absolutely wonky output:

[image: Arrows on either side, but wonky]

What's the correct way of getting the two arrows to be symmetrically opposite each other on the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you have a lot of control over the edge layout. But you can experiment with the [headport](https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/headport/) attribute values. Here are some examples.

##### Example 1

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;

  a:n -> a [color=blue]
  a:s -> a [color=green headport=center]
}
```

[View in editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20rankdir%3DLR%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20a%3An%20-%3E%20a%20%5Bcolor%3Dblue%5D%0D%0A%20%20a%3As%20-%3E%20a%20%5Bcolor%3Dgreen%20headport%3Dcenter%5D%0D%0A%7D)

[image: dot-1]

##### Example 2

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;

  a:ne -> a [color=blue]
  a:sw -> a [color=green headport=center]
}
```

[View in editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20rankdir%3DLR%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20a%3Ane%20-%3E%20a%20%5Bcolor%3Dblue%5D%0D%0A%20%20a%3Asw%20-%3E%20a%20%5Bcolor%3Dgreen%20headport%3Dcenter%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

[image: dot-2]

---

### Other layouts

You can also experiment with different layouts. Here are some options for the `circo` layout.

##### Example 3

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  layout="circo"

  a:n -> a:_ [color=blue headport=n]
  a:s -> a:_ [color=green headport=s dir=back]
}
```

[View in editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20rankdir%3DLR%3B%0D%0A%20%20layout%3D%22circo%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20a%3An%20-%3E%20a%3A_%20%5Bcolor%3Dblue%20headport%3Dn%5D%0D%0A%20%20a%3As%20-%3E%20a%3A_%20%5Bcolor%3Dgreen%20headport%3Ds%20dir%3Dback%5D%0D%0A%7D)

[image: circo-1]

##### Example 4

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR;
  layout="circo"

  a:nw -> a:w [color=blue headport=_]
  a:se -> a:e [color=green headport=_]
}
```

[View in editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20rankdir%3DLR%3B%0D%0A%20%20layout%3D%22circo%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20a%3Anw%20-%3E%20a%3Aw%20%5Bcolor%3Dblue%20headport%3D_%5D%0D%0A%20%20a%3Ase%20-%3E%20a%3Ae%20%5Bcolor%3Dgreen%20headport%3D_%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

[image: circo-2]